# Is the relative price level of two goods equal to the difference of their inflation rates?

Tags: inflation

So, a professor of mine wrote down in the solution of a problem that the ln(P1/P2) at time t is equal inflation of P1 minus the inflation of P2 at times t. However, I don't understand how that is possible, since the model I am trying to measure is static and not dynamic (i.e. the dependent variable itself is dated at time t and all the independent variables as well). Is there any relationship I need to know about?